# opposite of 'via'?

Tags: word-choice, internet

On the internet, you might have seen a lot of "**via**:xxx" links. But the originating site never seems to mention which sites has it been linked on. If it were, to, what should it put?

As an example, suppose somebody on twitter tweets this question and tags/hashes it as "**via**:english.SE". Now if english.SE were to also acknowledge it, what should it put?  **____**:twitter?

Comment: To start with, *via* means 'through', so it's not a vector (no *direction* component) -- it's *via* either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback):

> A **trackback** is one of the types of linkback methods for website authors to request notification when somebody links to one of their documents. This enables authors to keep track of who is linking to their articles. Some weblog software, such as SilverStripe, WordPress, Drupal, and Movable Type, supports automatic pingbacks where all the links in a published article can be pinged when the article is published. The term is used colloquially for any kind of linkback.

See also the more general term [linkback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkback), and the other specific types: [pingback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback), [refback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refback) and [WebMention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebMention).